# Ethereum Gas fee model

Tags: ethereumjs, eip-1559

I am trying to understand EIP 1559 Gas fee model.
I understand that the transaction fee is calculated as (Block base fee per gas + Max priority fee) * Gas used. So it means that we paid this much to the miner. I believe this is the reward for the miner to add my transaction in the block or the block in general. Now, I see another thing burnt fee which is calculated as (Base fee * Gas used). It's been said this fee is entirely burnt.
Is this correct?
Is this not part of the transaction fee that is added as reward to the miner?
How does this work?
From the link below,
https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0xbff2dd998ab58e02ae6d07384cb3effb3dbe12a3adb48c21e5f1d35310edfb59

```
Transaction Fee = 0.000031500000357 MATIC (Gas fee * Total Gas)
Gas fee = 0.000000001500000017 MATIC (Base fee + Max Priority) Correct?
Burnt fee = Base fee * Gas used
```

So, Is burnt fee a part of transaction?
Can somebody help me understand the equations here?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After referring to your transaction:

Using Gwei unit everywhere.

gas used: 21000 units

maxFeePerGas: 1.500000022

Base Fee: 0.000000017

maxPriorityFee: 1.5

Total matic spent(Tx fee or Gas fee): `(baseFee + maxPriorityFee) * gasUsed = 31500.000357`

Burnt: `base fee * gas used = 0.000357`

Txn Savings: `(maxFeePerGas - (baseFee + gasUsed)) * gasUsed = 0.000105`

Yes 31500.000357 Gwei was given to miner, just that burnt fee does not include the direct tip given to miner. You can refer to logs which indicate the transfer of matic to miner. Or alternatively you can refer to any tx on etherscan like:
https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x5e1ffe7d31318f5f6d4af4b19245ad7c915de5f012d734de36ee227d8bf195db#statechange